# How to change the output color of gulp-debug?

Tags: node.js, debugging, console, output, gulp

Due to a crash with Gulp, I could not debug what's happening behind. So I installed gulp-debug. I think it's throwing some lines of errors but with unreadable condition in my Windows system due to the output color. Is it possible to change this output color?

[image]

### Update

@pgreen2, Thanks for your reply.

```
gulp --no-color
```

allows complete no-color and so that I cannot distinguish between input and output. So is there any other way to change the particular blue color itself?

I searched across all the folders and noticed that it was hard coded. Developers have clearly stated like this as well

> // Don't use 'blue' not visible on cmd.exe

So I replaced to some hexadecimal color in **float.patch** under **core-util-is** with in the array of colors.

```
-inspect.colors = {
-  'bold' : [1, 22],
-  'italic' : [3, 23],
-  'underline' : [4, 24],
-  'inverse' : [7, 27],
-  'white' : [37, 39],
-  'grey' : [90, 39],
-  'black' : [30, 39],
-  '#FFF8DC' : [34, 39], // Blue got changed here
-  'cyan' : [36, 39],
-  'green' : [32, 39],
-  'magenta' : [35, 39],
-  'red' : [31, 39],
-  'yellow' : [33, 39]
-};
```

and in one more **core-util-is**. But still it's taking blue color itself. Also there is one more entry in readme.md script. Are they traversing that page as well? Please correct me if am doing anything wrong.

And is gulp-debug a good debug tool?

Comment: Would also love to know

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used `gulp-debug`, so I can't comment on the usefulness of it.  After looking at the source code (https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-debug/blob/master/index.js), the output colors are hard coded.  However, you can disable all colors for gulp, using `--no-color`.

Example:

```
gulp --no-color
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but if you use an alternative console like Console2 you can remap output colours as you see fit :)